# Weird pointer issue with strtok

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf, strtok

```
struct stat buf;
lstat(path, &buf)

char *p;
p = strtok(ctime(&buf.st_mtime)," ");
int i = 0;  

while (p != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",p);
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

The above code works and runs.

However, I don't understand why the pointer `p` is able to be just printed since it is pointing to the first token returned by `strtok()`.

When I tried to deference it by changing it to `*p` and print it out instead, it just returned segmentation fault. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: Because `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char`. `*p` is a `char`. Use the `%c` format specifier to print this character.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in line `p = strtok (NULL, " ");`?

Comment: @Dariusz `strtok(NULL, " ");` continues to tokenise the string on `" "` (shouldn't this be `' '` though?)

Comment: @Baldrickk yeah, you're right, strtok has an internal pointer stored. Didn't think it was unsafe. The 2nd param is OK, though. It's used as a list of chars.

Comment: Very bad form to call `strtok()` on a buffer owned by `ctime()`, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

As per the `C11` standard, chapter 7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` function, for `%s` format specifier,

> s
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.<sup>(280)</sup> Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.

So, basically, `%s` *expects* a pointer to the null-terminated `char` array, i.e., a *string*.

Then, as per the  [man page] (http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()`, it returns

> a pointer to the next token

Thus, in your code

```
 printf ("%s\n",p);
```

prints the whole *string*.OTOH, if you de-reference `p`, it gives a `char`, which is not a valid argument for `%s`, so it produces  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), creating the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` with `%s` format needs the address of the first char to be printed.

If you write `printf ("%s\n",*p);` you are passing to printf the first char as an address.

Eg. Str = "1234" ---> `printf ("%s\n",*p);` --> means that printf takes the string starting at address 0x00000031.